# PHAssetResourceManager usage?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios9, assets, fetch

I am trying to use `PHAssetResourceManager` to fetch data from an asset.

I can not find any examples anywhere about this.

I used to use `PHImageManager` but my app won't be released until next year
so I guess by that time most people will most likely have adopted the latest
iOS version anyways.

The code below returns "0" when trying to log the resource for a specified asset.

How do I work with `PHAssetResourceManager`?

My code:

```
    PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions;
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES], ];
    PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:fetchOptions];

    NSLog(@"fetchResult.count = %lu", fetchResult.count);

    PHAsset *asset = [fetchResult objectAtIndex: assetIndex];

    NSArray *resourceArray = [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset: asset];

    NSLog(@"resourceArray.count = %lu", resourceArray.count); //<<< returns 0?

    PHAssetResource *ar = [resourceArray objectAtIndex: 0];
    PHAssetResourceRequestOptions *arro = [[PHAssetResourceRequestOptions alloc] init];


    PHAssetResourceManager *arm = [PHAssetResourceManager defaultManager];


    [arm requestDataForAssetResource:ar options:arro
        dataReceivedHandler:^(NSData *assetData){
            NSLog(@"extractData dataReceivedHandler: %lu", assetData.length);
        }

        completionHandler:^(NSError *error){
            NSLog(@"extractData Error: %@", error);

        }
     ];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm calling the below method from a view controllers viewDidLoad method in the simulator and everything works.

```
- (void)readAsset:(NSInteger)assetIndex {
    PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES] ];
    PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:fetchOptions];

    if (assetIndex < fetchResult.count) {
        PHAsset *asset = fetchResult[assetIndex];
        NSArray *resourceArray = [PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset: asset];
        PHAssetResource *assetResource = resourceArray[0];

        PHAssetResourceManager *arm = [PHAssetResourceManager defaultManager];
        [arm requestDataForAssetResource:assetResource options:nil dataReceivedHandler:^(NSData * _Nonnull data) {
            NSLog(@"data.length = %lu", (unsigned long)data.length);
        } completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"no such asset.");
    }
}
```

The output was:

```
fetchResult.count = 5
data.length = 1048576
data.length = 1048576
data.length = 507598
data.length = 0
error = (null)
```

Can you figure out what is different between your code and mine? The only thing I see off hand is that you don't create a PHFetchOptions object before using it. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right, the simulator works fine, but on a physical device it won't work. In my case it's an iPhone 5S

Comment: yes, and probably because I don't have iOS 9.0+ installed on my device. hundreds of thousands of years of mankind evolution and I'm dumb enough to not update my os. Brb, will update real quick.